# cleanup nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a huge mess of a nested list that looks something like this, just longer:

```
fruit_mess = [['watermelon,0,1.0\n'], ['apple,0,1.0\n'], ['"pineapple",0,1.0\n'], ['"strawberry, banana",0,1.0\n'], ['peach plum pear,0,1.0\n'], ['"orange, grape",0,1.0\n']]
```

Ultimately I want something that looks like this:

```
neat_fruit = [['watermelon',0,1.0], ['apple',0,1.0], ['pineapple',0,1.0], ['strawberry, banana',0,1.0], ['peach plum pear',0,1.0], ['orange, grape',0,1.0]]
```

but I'm not sure how to deal with the double quotes in the quotes and how to split the fruits from the numbers, especially with the commas separating some of the fruits. I've tried a bunch of things, but everything just seems to make it even more of a mess. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `csv` module (in the standard library) to handle the double-quoted fruits with commas in their names:

```
import csv
import io

fruit_mess = [['watermelon,0,1.0\n'], ['apple,0,1.0\n'], ['"pineapple",0,1.0\n'], ['"strawberry, banana",0,1.0\n'], ['peach plum pear,0,1.0\n'], ['"orange, grape",0,1.0\n']]

# flatten the list of lists into a string:
data='\n'.join(item[0].strip() for item in fruit_mess)    
reader=csv.reader(io.BytesIO(data))
neat_fruit=[[fruit,int(num1),float(num2)] for fruit,num1,num2 in reader]

print(neat_fruit)    
# [['watermelon', 0, 1.0], ['apple', 0, 1.0], ['pineapple', 0, 1.0], ['strawberry, banana', 0, 1.0], ['peach plum pear', 0, 1.0], ['orange, grape', 0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Clever. Makes me wonder if this was a miss read csv file in the first place.

Comment: this looks great, but unfortunately i have python 2.5 which doesn't have the io module

Comment: @user808545: In that case, use `cStringIO.StringIO` in place of `io.BytesIO`.

Answer (score 1):

One more simple solution:

```
fruit_mess = [['watermelon,0,1.0\n'], ['apple,0,1.0\n'], ['"pineapple",0,1.0\n'], ['"strawberry, banana",0,1.0\n'], ['peach plum pear,0,1.0\n'], ['"orange, grape",0,1.0\n']]
for i,x in enumerate(fruit_mess):
    data = x[0].rstrip('\n').rsplit(',', 2)
    fruit_mess[i] = [data[0], int(data[1]), float(data[2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex-based solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'("[^"]*"|[^,]*),(\d+),([\d.]+)')
>>> neat_fruit = []
>>> for item in fruit_mess:
...     match = regex.match(item[0])
...     result = [match.group(1).strip('"'), int(match.group(2)), float(match.group(3))]
...     neat_fruit.append(result)
...
>>> neat_fruit
[['watermelon', 0, 1.0], ['apple', 0, 1.0], ['pineapple', 0, 1.0], ['strawberry,
 banana', 0, 1.0], ['peach plum pear', 0, 1.0], ['orange, grape', 0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: hmmm for some reason this gives me                               result = [match.group(1).strip('"'), int(match.group(2)), float(match.group(3))]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group', not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This probably means that the match failed on one of the strings. The regex works on the sample data in your question, but if there are other formats in your actual data, the regex might fail.